# Is the Ubuntu 12.04 server support linux kernel version 2.4.20?

Tags: networking, server, versions, traffic

because I will use HTB for ubuntu server 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the kernel versions available in the official Ubuntu 12.04 repositories are:

- 3.2.0, provided by package **linux-generic**
- 3.5.0, provided by package **linux-generic-lts-quantal**
- 3.8.0, provided by package **linux-generic-lts-raring**

If you manage to install any kernel from a not official repository, it would be unsupported.

Comment: Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 does?        Anyway Thanks. :)